# Command line history & tab-completion for sftp in OS X Terminal.app

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal.app, sftp, autocomplete

I use Terminal.app constantly. When connecting via `ssh` to remote *nix systems, I can continue to use `tab` to complete command names and `arrow-up/down` to navigate the command history. However, with `sftp` this does not work, and I get `[`-escaped sequences for the latter and a literal tab for the former.

Any way to get this to work? Anything to do with `readline`?

Comment: This solution worked best for me https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168157/tab-completion-for-hosts-defined-in-ssh-config-doesnt-work-anymore-on-yosemi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SFTP from MacOS to Ubuntu does not support arrow keys, backspace, or tab completion](https://superuser.com/questions/1543592/sftp-from-macos-to-ubuntu-does-not-support-arrow-keys-backspace-or-tab-complet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [with-readline](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2005/withreadline.html). There's an example using sftp there.

Comment: Only problem is it's shows password.

Comment: .. and it completes based on the local folder, not the remote folder

Answer (score 5):

Having tried to install with-readline on OSX 10.7.5 I ran into linker errors.

While trying to find a solution to this problem I discovered that [MacPorts](http://macports.org) has a port of [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org) which includes the `sftp` utility compiled with readline support.  MacPorts also sets this version of `sftp` as the default.

Comment: The same solution can be applied if you prefer Homebrew, their version of `homebrew/dupes/openssh` also comes with tab completion.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [yafc](http://yafc.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Type this into the Terminal:

```
which sftp
```

If the result were `/usr/bin/sftp`, means you are using the macOS built-in SFTP version that is out of date compared two the GNU version. More details [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-240.40.1/openssh/sftp-client.c.auto.html).

You could install the Homebrew version — which is the GNU version — instead

```
brew install openssh
```

And list the `openssh` install path:

```
brew list openssh
```

Tou would see some binary here for example:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/.bottle/etc/ (12 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/scp
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/sftp
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/slogin
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh-add
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh-agent
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh-keygen
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh-keyscan
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/libexec/ (4 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/sbin/sshd
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/share/man/ (15 files)
```

Now type:

```
which sftp
```

the result would be `/usr/local/bin/sftp`,which is a soft link of `/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/sftp`

Then try the Homebrew version of SFTP and enjoy it!

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you! I'm a newbee and not familier with this.

Comment: Bear in mind that with the standard OpenSSH (as opposed to the one that is shipped with macOS) you [won't](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/419965/219257) be able to save passwords for SSH keys in the macOS Keychain.