# SFTP from MacOS to Ubuntu does not support arrow keys, backspace, or tab completion

Tags: macos, ubuntu, bash, sftp

When using sftp from a Mac to an Ubuntu machine arrow keys, backspace and tab completion do not work. Specifically, arrows keys and backspace result in character sequences and tab just inserts a tab. However, when using sftp from the Ubuntu machine to the Mac, I have no issues. I cannot figure out where the difference is. My goal is to be able to sftp into the Ubuntu machine and use arrow keys, backspace, and tab completion.

SHELL:

I have tried both `zsh` and `bash` on both machines (Upgrading from /bin/sh is the fix suggested on most other similar questions)

SSHD_CONFIG:

I have tried both `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` and `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` within the sshd_config file on the Ubuntu machine. The Mac is using `/usr/libexec/sftp-server`.

I realize that these settings are different so I suspect this causes the difference, but I do not know enough to understand precisely what this difference is nor how I could resolve it. I also cannot find much documentation on what these different sftp servers are.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command line history & tab-completion for sftp in OS X Terminal.app](https://superuser.com/questions/176340/command-line-history-tab-completion-for-sftp-in-os-x-terminal-app)

Answer (score 6):

Type this into the Terminal:

```
which sftp
```

If the result were `/usr/bin/sftp`, means you are using the macOS built-in SFTP version that is out of date compared two the GNU version. More details [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-240.40.1/openssh/sftp-client.c.auto.html).

You could install the Homebrew version — which is the GNU version — instead

```
brew install openssh
```

And list the `openssh` install path:

```
brew list openssh
```

Tou would see some binary here for example:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/.bottle/etc/ (12 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/scp
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/sftp
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/slogin
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh-add
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh-agent
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh-keygen
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/ssh-keyscan
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/libexec/ (4 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/sbin/sshd
/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/share/man/ (15 files)
```

Now type:

```
which sftp
```

the result would be `/usr/local/bin/sftp`,which is a soft link of `/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.4p1_2/bin/sftp`

Then try the Homebrew version of SFTP and enjoy it!

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: This answer is rock solid, but [the other question](https://superuser.com/q/176340/167207) is 10 years old and — as such — this is the question that should be removed as a dupe and [that other question](https://superuser.com/q/176340/167207) should be the one where your answer stands.

Answer (score 1):

> with-readline is a small program that allows the GNU Readline library to be used with arbitrary programs, without having to recompile those programs. It is useful for improving the user interface of simple terminal-based programs which for whatever reason have not been modified to use Readline themselves.[link](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/sw/withreadline.html)

You can install with-readline to support arrow keys and backspace.

However,tab is only supported on local side, you can not complete filename from remote side.

Installation as detail below:

```
brew install with-readline
echo 'alias sftp="with-readline sftp"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any ideas for also tab completion? It works when sftping into Mac, so it ought to be possible...

Comment: @user3167101It depends on how the SFTP software programmed,the official one clearly doesn't support these features. When you sftping into Mac,for instance,from windows,then actuallly you use the SFTP software programmed for windows.SFTP software has different versions,maybe you can try the third party one.

Comment: @user3167101 see https://superuser.com/a/1622315/965558 it's a better answer

Answer (score 0):

Good news! sftp (OpenSSH) has a build configure option to enable editline (readline history) support. I cannot possibly fathom WHY any sane person would build it without this, as it gives all the crucial features you seek (up-arrow command history, tab-completion of local and remote filenames, etc.) with zero caveats. I enabled it when I built OpenSSH 8.7p1 on my jailbroken iPad but I'm sure it works equally well anywhere.